# Away3d equirectangular to cubic projection

Tags: video, away3d

Trying to create a 360 video player which uses equirectangular video as source files. Exactly like these on flickr, but videos, not still images.
http://www.flickr.com/groups/equirectangular/pool/

I've come across this project on github, but it projects the original source onto a videotexture inside a sphere, which I think is less efficient and also has the problem of being limited to just 1 texture with a maximum size of 2048 pixels.

https://github.com/Visuall-Interactive/OVP-basic

Can any Away3d experts suggest how I would map a equirectangular video source to the inside of a cube (ie convert from equirectangular to cubic)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In my early Away3D days I took over a project that was trying to map everything to a spherical environment. I had the assets re-rendered to use cubic mapping onto either planes or inverted cubes. We went from 4 fps to 30 fps at the time.

I would recommend using cubic mapping onto a Skybox like setup (inverted cube or 6 planes) and pre-process the videos to match. This would be the most efficient way to get both better quality and performance.

The cube/plane approach also has the advantage of having 6 textures and therefore allow for much higher resolution. But in theory you could also split a sphere into segments and use several textures.

Keep in mind that the VideoTexture is slow and not GPU accelerated. Can you re-render or pre-process these videos? Or do you have to load them as-is?

Comment: Thanks, yes have to load them as is. 720P mp4's with H.264 encoding. Beginning to think the best solution is to NOT use Away3d but rather Flash Native3d...but I'm not a 3D math wizard

Comment: There's not much that can be done until we get access the to decoded image on the GPU. That has been requested but, I don't think it's a big priority for Adobe.